# Preventing duplicate records across multiple connections using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, transactions

I have two separate processes, each with it's own database connection, inserting product records into a table. Before a process inserts a product into the table, it checks to see if a product with the same properties already exists. If the product already exists, the process modifies one field and saves the product. Otherwise, the process creates a new product.

I'm wrapping the find and create in a transaction, but duplicate products still get inserted because ActiveRecord transactions only act on a single database connection.

What's the best way to prevent duplicate products from being inserted across multiple database connections using ActiveRecord and Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [multi-field key](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?52,161230,161236#msg-161236) on the table, which will enforce unique combinations of those fields.  Then, your app can just watch for database INSERT errors.

Comment: Exactly, the database is the single source of truth here. Let *it* decide if the product to be inserted is unique.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm going with for now.